# Power Query - Function IF null

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I have a specific function in Power Query like this:

```
let Func_Test = (input) =>
    input/1000 + 500
in
    Func_Test
```

The challange is now, that the input can contain null.
If this is the case, then I get an error.
How can I avoid this directly in the function?

Comment: What is the error?  I cannot reproduce your problem.  If I input *null*, the result is *null*. Please provide sufficient information so I can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
try input/1000 + 500 otherwise null
```

Answer (score 1):

If I input *null* into your function, I get *null* as a response.

However if I don't input anything, the response is an error message :`Expression.Error: 0 arguments were passed to a function which expects 1.`

For this latter problem, just make the argument optional:

```
let Func_Test = (optional input) =>
    input/1000 + 500
in
    Func_Test
```